# My login system is secure?

Tags: php, sql

I have made this:

```
<?php

// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("cavallo", $connection);
session_start(); // Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql = mysql_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session = $row['username'];
if (!isset($login_session)) {
    mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

It is the protocol of a session made by me, I fear it is not safe.

Do you think there is a way to crack this method?

login.php file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d7db3ea76fc4258d6512

Update: I re-created all the script with online guides for a secure login.thanks for helping me and reported the problem

Comment: How is `$_SESSION['login_user']` populated? Your code looks like it might be susceptible to injection attacks.

Comment: i have update the post with login.php file

Comment: Go live with it then come back and tell us if it were. Edit: Short answer; *no*.

Comment: I think if you are using `mysql_` and saving important credentials to session, then no definitely not safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing passwords as strings is not secure.

[Read this](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). I think it may help you.

And read more about SQL injection, password hashing, using salt with passwords, session hijacking.

Answer (score 1):

No. it's highly insecure.

Follow these step to secure your login system:

1. Store password in hash format so that your employees can't see your user password.

   - How to hash your password:

     a. Get user password and immediately hash them.

     ```
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $password = hash('sha256',$password);
     ```

     b. Store this hash password in your database.
2. Now how to check user credential.

   ```
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

   settype($username,"string");
   $password = hash('sha256',$password);

   $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ? and password = ?');
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $username,$password);

   $stmt->execute();

   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       // do something with $row
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Use prepared statements and parameterized queries is impossible for an attacker to inject malicious SQL.**
You can try that by PDO and Mysqli query.

Example of PDO

PDO is that the SQL statement you pass to prepare is parsed and compiled by the database server.

```
//setting up connection
$dbconn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
//prepare query
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
$prepareQuery = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (:column)');

$perpareQuery->execute(array('column' => $user_check));

foreach($perpareQuery as $row) {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a fundamental bug: you're only checking whether the username exists - you're not even looking at the input password. So if I type in any existing user's username, your login page will grant me access. At the very least fix that bug; then go look at the other problems (SQL injection, no password hashing) that others have mentioned.